# Send Email through Outlook Shared Mailbox in Django

Tags: django, email, office365

Currently I have been using my licensed outlook email address to send emails in django using the below settings

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = smtp.outlook.office365.com
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER  = 'xyz@company.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Password'
```

Recently we have setup a new shared mailbox 'noreply@company.com' to replace it with my email but having issues sending emails as it doesn't accepts the credentials (i.e password) and throws an SMTPAuthenticationError exception.

Is it possible to send emails using the shared mailbox over smtp server ? If yes, how can I achieve this in Django ?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved:

All the email settings in the posted question remain the same. Added the shared mailbox email address to a new variable in settings file:

```
FROM_EMAIL = "noreply@company.com"
```

and updated the 'from_email' argument in send_mail method with the new setting

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

send_mail('Subject', 'Message', settings.FROM_EMAIL, ["abc@company.com"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The mailbox must have a license allocated to be able to send emails. When sending through SMTP, you must specify the credentials of the shared mailbox, not the credentials of some other user who has access delegate to it.

Comment: As far I know, shared mailbox don't have a license tagged to them. So that means its not possible to send emails using a shared mailbox ?

Comment: That is correct. It can receive messages, but not send them until a license is allocated.